# Create Windows LiveCD

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, iso

I'm trying to figure out how to create a LiveCD ISO with a Windows operating system. It can be any Windows OS (Win7, Win8, Server 2012, etc). I can't seem to find any method to create a bootable livecd ISO? I'm trying to create an ISO that will boot a Windows OS so i can perform work on servers.

I'm used to creating a variety of Linux liveCD's, but I can't figure out how to make a Windows LiveCD ISO?

Any suggestions on how to do this is greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1):

A "live" version of Windows is called [WinPE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825110.aspx) (Preinstallation Environment). Quoting the [MS Technet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn293200.aspx) on how to create a WinPE CD/DVD:

> Install the Windows ADK
>
> ```
> Install the following features from the Windows Assessment and Deployment Kit (Windows ADK):
>     Deployment Tools: includes the Deployment and Imaging Tools Environment.
>
>     Windows Preinstallation Environment : includes the files used to install Windows PE.
> ```
>
> Install Windows PE to a DVD, a CD, or an ISO file
>
> ```
> Click Start, and type deployment. Right-click Deployment and Imaging Tools Environment and then select Run as administrator.
>
> Create a working copy of the Windows PE files. Specify either x86 or amd64:
>
> copype amd64 C:\WinPE_amd64
>
> Create an ISO file containing the Windows PE files:
>
> MakeWinPEMedia /ISO C:\WinPE_amd64 C:\WinPE_amd64\WinPE_amd64.iso
>
> To burn a DVD or CD: In Windows Explorer, right-click the ISO file, and select Burn disc image > Burn, and follow the prompts.
> ```

Be sure to read the ADK's license agreement, I couldn't find the latest online. Usage of WinPE is usually granted for maintenance and troubleshooting of other systems online, it's not to be used as a thin client or similar.